# How can I make a given number of Promises run at the same time on Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

So I'm creating this scraping application that essentially uses a REST API for several entities on the server. The main functionallity is just:

```
let buffer = []
for(entity in entities){
   let data = await scrapingProcessForAnEntity(entity);
   buffer.push(data)
}
```

I oversimplified the script because the scraping process and how it is stored is not relevant, the point is that I have this function `scrapingProcessForAnEntity` that gets and returns all the information I need in a Promise.
The thing is, since there are a lot of entities, I want to make it so that I can run the process for multiple entities at a time, and once one of the processes is finished, a new one takes its place. I made some tests trying to use an array of Promises and `Promise.race()` but I can't figure how to make the finished Promise quit the array. I also can't just run the process for all entities at once with a `Promise.all()` because the server is not capable of handling too many requests at once. It should be ok if I limit it to 3~5 entities.

What I'm trying to do is to essentially "have a single line for 3 cashiers at a supermarket". As soon as the one of the cashier is free (which is equal to the first Promise being finished) the next client can immediately proceed (enter the promises array).

My current implementation is:

```
let promises = []
let buffer = []
async function run(){
   for(entity in entities){
      addPromise(() => scrapingProcessForAnEntity(entity))
   }
}

async function addPromise(prom){
   if(promises.length >= 3){ //In this example I'm trying to make it run for up to 3 at a time
      await moveQueue()
   }
   promises.push(prom())
}

async function moveQueue(){
   if(promises.length < 3){
      return
   }
   let data = await Promise.race(promises)
   buffer.push(data)
   promises.splice(promises.indexOf(data), 1) //<---- This is where I'm struggling at
   //how can I remove the finished promised from the array? 
}
```

Adding the data into to the buffer is not directly implemented in the Promise itself because there's processing involved in it and I'm not sure if adding the data from 2 promises at the same time might cause an issue.

I also implemented a way to clear all the promises on the end. My only struggle is how to find which promise inside of the array has finished so that it can be replaced.

Comment: My question is, Why do you want to delete only resolved promises from the array? Do you want to retry the rejected one? If no, You can simply flush the array because no need to keep it there if it resolved or rejected right?

Comment: I want to delete only the finished ones, be it resolved or rejected, because the time it takes for an entity process to finish is not constant. So if there's "a big entity" it won't block the execution, it will hold one slot on the array but the others one can be used since they will probably be finished earlier.

Comment: I also explained on another comment below that "if I don't remove the finished promises from the array, the Promise.race will keep returning the already finished promises. My issue is how to find the next finished"

Comment: You are using ``await Promise.race` that returns the earliest resolved data. Let's say you managed to remove the promise that resolved from the array. But you never know when the other promises resolve, How are you gonna remove it from the array? The approach is quite wrong here.

Comment: The idea is that as soon as a Promise get finished it will be removed, that's what `moveQueue` does. This function is called whenever I'm trying to add a new Promise into the already full array. The function `addProm` after waiting for `moveQueue` will add another promise. 
This process will be repeated as *wait -> remove -> add* until I reach the last 3 entities. At that point I have another function that uses a `Promise.all` to resolve all the remaining Promises.

Answer (score 1):

```
let entities = [] // all entities
let batch = []; // holding current batch of promises
let buffer = []; // holding all the scraped data

function scrapingProcessForBatch(batch) {
   return Promise.all(batch.map(entity => scrapingProcessForAnEntity(entity)))
}

async function addBatch() {
   batch = [];
   if (!entities.length) return; // if no more entities, exit

   for (let i=0; i<3; i++) {
      let entity = entities.pop();
      if (entity) batch.push(entity);
   }

   let data = await scrapingProcessForBatch(batch);
   buffer.push(...data);

   await addBatch();
}

async function run() {
   await addBatch();
   // all data in buffer array now
}
```

This ensures that you are always processing 3 entities at a time, and as soon as one batch finishes, a new one will take its place. You can tweak as per your preference.

Comment: `Promise.all` will return array of data from all the 3 promises. You need to spread it when push. `buffer.push(...data)`

Comment: My current working solution for this problem is to do like you say. The thing is, the process does not have a consistent time for every entity, it depends on how much data it holds.
The one that takes the longest might be up to 5mins. If I use Promise.all the script will only be able to get the data from 3 entities during that time while the Promise.race could get many more.

Comment: I would suggest using a combination of both Promise.all() and Promise.race(). You can divide your entities into batches of 3 and use Promise.all() to run those batches concurrently. Then, as soon as one batch finishes, use Promise.race() to replace it with a new batch.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the below solution works as you want. Here I keep the `tasks` queue unlimited but control the execution threshold.

```js
    let tasks = []
    let buffer = []
    let runningTasks = 0

    async function run(){
       for(entity in entities){
          addPromise(() => scrapingProcessForAnEntity(entity))
       }
       
       processQueue();
    }

    async function addPromise(prom){
       tasks.push(prom)
    }

    async function processQueue() {

       // [1] initally runningTasks = 0
       if (runningTasks === 3 || tasks.length === 0) {
          return;
       }
       
       // [2] take 1st task and remove it from array
       const taskPromise = tasks[0]();
       tasks.shift();

       // [3] executes 1st task, won't wait
       taskPromise.then((data) => {
          buffer.push(data);
          runningTasks -= 1;
          
          // Check again if there is anything to execute
          processQueue();
       });
       
       // [4] If running tasks is less than 3 and if tasks has more, execute again
       // If runningTasks already 3, Then no need to execute now, It will be handled in then() above
       if ( runningTasks < 3 && tasks.length > 0) {
          processQueue();
       }
    }
```

Comment: `tasks.slice(0, 1);` does nothing. Did you mean `shift()`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I meant `splice`. Removing from the queue. Of course can use shift too

Answer (score 0):

you can use the map method to execute multiple promises .for example

**you can chunk the entities how many you want before making the promises**

```js
// Function to chunk an array into smaller arrays
function chunkArray(array, chunkSize) {
  const chunks = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += chunkSize) {
    chunks.push(array.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
  }
  return chunks;
}

// Assuming scrapingProcessForAnEntity returns a Promise
const scrapingProcessForAnEntity = (query) => {
  // Your asynchronous API call logic here
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Example asynchronous operation (replace with your actual API call)
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`API call for query: ${query}`);
      resolve(`Data for query: ${query}`);
    }, 1000); // Simulated delay of 1 second
  });
};

const entities = ['entity1', 'entity2', 'entity3', 'entity4', 'entity5', 'entity6'];

// Chunk the entities into arrays of size 3
const chunkedEntities = chunkArray(entities, 3);

// Map over the chunks and perform asynchronous operations using Promise.all
const allPromises = chunkedEntities.map(chunk => {
  const promiseQuery = chunk.map(entity => scrapingProcessForAnEntity(entity));
  return Promise.all(promiseQuery);
});

// Flatten the results if needed (if you want a flat array of fulfilled promises)
const fullfilledPromises = Promise.all(allPromises.flat());

fullfilledPromises.then(results => {
  console.log('All API calls completed:', results);
}).catch(error => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

here allEntities will have the array of promises and Promise.all method will execute it prallelly

Comment: I'll edit this on the question, but the main reason for me to limit how many should be running at a time is because the server is not capable of handling too many requests at once.

Comment: @RobsonLuan consider you have array of 10 entities but server will accept 5 at a time ,so what you have to do is chunk the entities into 5 and do a nested loop to fetch that chunked promises value using the flat() method

Comment: This will generate the same outcome as the one on the other answer right? It will be able to run 5 at a time but the processes will only "move foward" once all those 5 are finished. This is an ok solution and I have already implemented something similar, but I'm just trying to look for a way to dinamically add/remove the Promises that are running.

Comment: then you can use Promise.race() method that's it

Comment: It does work for the first bunch of processes, but if I don't remove the finished promises from the array, the Promise.race will keep returning the already finished promises. My issue is how to find the next finished

Comment: Once a promise settles using Promise.race, it cannot be directly accessed again. The nature of Promise.race is to resolve or reject as soon as any of the promises in the input array settles. Once that happens, the winning promise's value or rejection reason is captured, and the other promises' outcomes are not tracked.

Answer (score 0):

This is more efficient than chunking. The idea is to count the currently executing promises, and launch the next one only when that count falls below the limit.

```js
class LimitedResourceExecutor {
  #size
  #queue
  #running

  constructor(size=1) {
    this.#size = size
    this.#queue = []
    this.#running = 0
  }
  
  get size() { return this.#size }

  // enqueue a task, then check if it should be run
  call(obj, func, ...args) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.#queue.push([resolve, reject, obj, func, args])
      this.#runQueue()
    })
  }

  // run a task if it can be run, check again afterwards
  async #runQueue() {
    if (this.#queue.length && this.#running < this.size) {
      this.#running++
      const [resolve, reject, obj, func, args] = this.#queue.shift()
      try {
        const result = await func.call(obj, ...args)
        resolve(result)
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err)
      } finally {
        this.#running--
        this.#runQueue()
      }
    }
  }
}


// From https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235/240443
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

// just a little test function
let id = 0
let start = new Date().getTime()
async function sleepAndLog(ms) {
  const thisId = ++id
  console.log(new Date() - start, thisId, "starting", ms)
  await sleep(ms)
  console.log(new Date() - start, thisId, "finished", ms)
  return thisId
}

// only two tasks in parallel
const lre = new LimitedResourceExecutor(2)
const timings = [4000, 1000, 1000, 2000, 3000, 1000]
// construct a promise list
const promises = timings.map(ms => lre.call(null, sleepAndLog, ms))
// Promise.all still works, results coming in the correct order
Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
  console.log("DONE")
  console.log(JSON.stringify(results))
})
```

Check the console log to see that there are never more than two tasks executing at the same time. Also note that even though task 1 is long, tasks 3 is executed immediately after task 2 is done, without waiting for task 1 as well, which is the behaviour you would get by chunked execution.